# Is It possible to move the avatar programmatically or specify position in Autodesk.AEC.Minimap3DExtension

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Autodesk.AEC.Minimap3DExtension provides a 3d and 2d sync forge viewer where a user can use 2d viewer and move the avatar to navigate. In order to navigate user has to move the avatar or a dot icon in 2d viewer to navigate in 3d model.

My question is where is there any possibility where I can send the set of coordinates which are with me and can I move the avatar programmatically so that user don't have to do so.

here is any example why I am asking so,
I have a geometry on my forge viewer which is on 2D and I am looking to make a first person view over that geometry.
So If I have all the points of geometry I want to make it use with Autodesk.AEC.Minimap3DExtension so that I can move first person to different views

here is the sample I am rereferring to [link](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-revit-levels-and-2d-minimap-your-3d)

I had been following this wonderful blog [link](https://d1r98t40ydopvd.cloudfront.net/ja/node/1765)
with the help of this I am aware little bit aware how to work with 2dto3d
here in above link

```
const worldPos = sheetToWorld(intersection.intersectPoint, viewer2D.model, 
viewer3D.model);
```

the above line of code gives me worldPos with which a geometric point is
created in the 3d viewer in spite of creating a geometry how can I use to
show view of that particular place

basically in this below line of code which transits camera from one position to another

```
viewer.navigation.setRequestTransition(true, newPos, newTarget, 
viewer.navigation.getHorizontalFov());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad you like the blog post :)

After reading the question I have the impression that you have already answered it yourself. If you have some kind of a geometry, let's say a polyline, overlaid on top of the 2D drawing, you can use the same logic explained in the blog post, but when calling `viewer.hitTest`, instead of passing in some mouse coordinates, you would just supply one of the points of your polyline.

Instead of:

```js
viewer2D.container.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    const intersection = viewer2D.hitTest(ev.clientX, ev.clientY);
    viewer3D.isolate([]);
    if (intersection) {
        viewer3D.isolate(intersection.dbId);
        const worldPos = sheetToWorld(intersection.intersectPoint, viewer2D.model, viewer3D.model);
        if (worldPos) {
            let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            mesh.position.set(worldPos.x, worldPos.y, worldPos.z);
            viewer3D.overlays.addMesh(mesh, 'indicator-scene');
        }
    }
});
```

It could look something like this:

```js
function moveCameraToPointOnSheet(x, y) {
    const intersection = viewer2D.hitTest(x, y);
    if (intersection) {
        const worldPos = sheetToWorld(intersection.intersectPoint, viewer2D.model, viewer3D.model);
        if (worldPos) {
            const eyeVec = viewer3D.navigation.getEyeVector();
            const newPos = worldPos;
            const newTarget = newPos.clone().add(eyeVec);
            const fov = viewer3D.navigation.getHorizontalFov();
            viewer3D.navigation.setRequestTransition(true, newPos, newTarget, fov);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Petr, m stuck with one more issue my geometry is on floor and so the new position which I send to camera, the camera shows the view of under the floor can that be fixed with some maths ?

Comment: After computing the `worldPos` you can try modifying its `y` or `z` component to shift it upwards by a small fixed amount.